# Submit button not working in Laravel Crud using Ajax Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, crud

I am trying to submit the form after filling out the form fields but it is not getting submitted and also not getting any kind of errors on console as well as network.

My create.blade for form:

```
<form method="POST" class="create_form" id="form" action="{{ route('details.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data"> @csrf <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="name">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="age">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="address">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Contact</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="contact">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="email">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Gender:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked>Male
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Qualification </td>
    <td>
      <select name="qualification">
        <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
        <option value="HSC">HSC</option>
        <option value="UG">UG</option>
        <option value="PG">PG</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hobbies:</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Trading">Trading
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Games">Games
  </td>
  </tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Music">Music
  </td>
  </tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="Swimming">Swimming
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Profile Picture</td>
    <td>
      <input type="file" name="profilepic">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Signature</td>
    <td>
      <input type="file" name="signature">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="save_create">Save</button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="back">Back</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</form>
```

My ajax jquery code for submit button:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.create_form', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{ route('details.store') }}",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            window.location.href = ("{{ route('details.index') }}");
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Errors :", error);
        }
    });
});
```

I also tried to get the result and error in the console but still getting none of them.
Also I used

```
<input type="submit" class=save_create>
```

but still not getting submitted.

Comment: If you're just going to redirect immediately after the ajax finishes, why bother with ajax to begin with? It adds complexity for no obvious benefit

Comment: It will not directly redirect. before that it must send the data from the form to the store method of Controller of laravel

Comment: @PranavSompura but it will be handle by controller... like if data store successfully then it will return route ohterwise it will display error into blade file

Comment: but the button itself is not clicking and submitting and I dont know bcz of what. I am not getting any kind of error in console

Comment: @PranavSompura must be use of AJAX?

Comment: Can't understand what are you trying to say please elaborate

Comment: `It will not directly redirect. before that it must send the data from the form to the store method of Controller of laravel`...ok sure, but my point was: why add the overhead of using AJAX to do that? Why not just have a normal form postback? Less code, less hassle, easier to debug. The whole point of AJAX is to let you stay on the same page afterwards. So if you intend to redirect to another page after AJAX, there is really no advantage to using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class DetailController extends Controller
    {
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            // Validate the incoming request data
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required|string',
                'age' => 'required|numeric',
                'address' => 'required|string',
                'contact' => 'required|string',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'gender' => 'required|string',
                'qualification' => 'required|string',
                'hobbies' => 'nullable|array',
                'profilepic' => 'nullable|image',
                'signature' => 'nullable|image',
            ]);
    
            // Store the data in the database or perform any desired operations
            // Example: Creating a new details
            $details = Detail::create($validatedData);
    
            // Redirect to the details.index route
            return redirect()->route('details.index')->with('success', 'Detail added successfully!');
        }
    }
```

you need to handle like this Instead of AJAX

if you want ajax then use like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form').submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
            
            // Serialize the form data
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('details.store') }}",
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    // Redirect to details.index route on success
                    window.location.href = "{{ route('details.index') }}";
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    // Handle error if necessary
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DetailsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // Validate the incoming request data
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            // Validation rules for your form fields
        ]);

        // Store the data in the database or perform any desired operations
        // Example: Creating a new user
        $user = User::create($validatedData);

        // Return a JSON response if needed
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I have to integrate my project with ajax so I have to use ajax and previously also I have created crud appliaction using both but never got this kind of trouble yet. The answer you have given is perfect but only using laravel not ajax and I need to send the response from controller to ajax in json format

Comment: @PranavSompura i update my code try it

Comment: still submit button not working

Comment: @PranavSompura what's ur console say when you click submit?

Comment: nothing just blank

Answer (score 0):

You can use in html form id and this form 2 file add so you can use form_data.append like that

```
 <input id="save_apply_leave" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline btn-info btn-lg" value="{{ __('Apply') }}"/>
    
<script>
 $(document.body).on('click','#save_apply_leave',function() {

 var front_passport = $("#front_passport").prop("files")[0];
           
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append("branch", branch);
            form_data.append("accomodation", accomodation);
            form_data.append("front_passport", front_passport);

                 $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url('attendance/updateAttendanceApply') }}',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 
                      $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: form_data,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                   if (response.status == 1){
                   console.log("approve");
                  }

           });

      });
</script>
```